# Is it possible to run multiple scenes in blender while only keeping one visible?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, scene

I was wondering if it were at all possible to run a scene in blender game engine while being able to selectively toggle visibility? In other words, have a scene running physics, but only displaying it when a player selects it from a menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you see what the camera sees.

Ensure the camera of the "hidden scene" does not show anything.

Comment: Some good methods for "not displaying anything" include facing the wrong way, and setting really short clipping distances